# I keep getting an NPE when checking for a sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to check to see if a table exists in and SQLite Database with Android using this in my SQLiteOpenHelper file

```
// Check to see if a table exists
public boolean isTableExists(String tblName) {
    String existQuery = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE name ='" + tblName + "' and type='table'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(existQuery, null);

    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

The call from my Activity is

```
if(db.isTableExists("characters") == false){
        Intent p = new Intent("com.tml.rpgtodo.CREATECHARACTER");
        startActivity(p);
    }
```

I keep getting a NullPointerException on the row with the if statement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `db` is null when you call `if(db.isTableExists("characters") == false)`.

I also see that you initialize db inside of "isTableExists()".  Is that a *different* "db"?

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! And to answer your question, yes, they are in different files.